# Flutter/Dart - Colorize extension for hex color value visualization

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code, flutter

I'd like to visualize **Flutter color** values in **VisualStudio Code** editor. Is there a simple VSCode plugin which can do this?

[image]

I tried `Colorize` but it seems not to work for `*.dart` files.

Ideally the extension would highlight the following formats:

`Color(0xFF575A72)`

`CupertinoColors.white` and `Colors.white`

`HexColor("#b74093")` and `HexColor("b74093")`

etc.

Comment: Open an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues or post your screenshot on https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/807 and I'll see if there's an easy way I can do this.